# Powershell find applications site collection is using

Tags: powershell, site-collection, searchserviceapplication

Is there a way in powershell to find out what Service Apps a site collection is using.
Having some trouble with a site collection that was created when we had a faulty Search Service app, created a new Search Service app, items in that site collection were not coming back so created a new site collection and that now works fine. So just want to understand why the first site collection isn't working.

Comment: Kindly check here...http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-how-series-administration